# How to return to the application from webview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview

After payment via webview I need the user to be automatically redirected back to the application? How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin#-installing-tab-). 
launch your payment gateway in a custom rectangle

```
final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();

flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(url,
  fullScreen: false,
  rect: new Rect.fromLTWH(
    0.0,
    0.0,
    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    300.0,
  ),
);
```

And listen for success url in this method

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {

});
```

and navigate or pop to the page you want to goto.